# Trouble doing grep only 10 digit number from a file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, grep

I am unable to grep exact only 10 digit number I wanted from a zone file.

Example zone file is:

```
> cat /var/named/test.com.db
; cPanel first:11.11.0-BETA_16994 (update_time):1468656855 Cpanel::ZoneFile::VERSION:1.3 hostname:server.test.com latest:11.56.0.13
; Zone file for test.com
$TTL 14400
test.com.      86400   IN      SOA     ns1.test.com.     cpanel.test.com.  (
                                                2016071602 ;Serial Number
                                                14400 ;refresh
                                                7200 ;retry
                                                2419200 ;expire
                                                43200   )
; test.com.    86400   IN      SOA     ns1.test.com.       serveralerts.test.com.        ( ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT
;                                               2015061700 ;Serial Number ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT
;                                               86400 ;refresh ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT
;                                               7200 ;retry ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT
;                                               3600000 ;expire ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT
;                                               86400 ;minimum ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT
;       ) ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT

test.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns1.test.com.
test.com.      86400   IN      NS      ns2.test.com.
; test.com.    86400   IN      NS      ns1.test.com. ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT
; test.com.    86400   IN      NS      ns2.test.com. ; Previous value removed by cPanel restore auto-merge on 20160510102706 GMT


test.com.      14400   IN      A       192.168.1.100

localhost       14400   IN      A       127.0.0.1

test.com.      14400   IN      MX      0       test.com.

mail    14400   IN      CNAME   test.com.
www     14400   IN      CNAME   test.com.
ftp     14400   IN      CNAME   test.com.
webdisk 14400   IN      A       192.168.1.100
cpcalendars     14400   IN      A       192.168.1.100
test.com. IN TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:192.168.1.100 ~all"
```

I want to see only the current serial number **2016071602** from the zone file on grep output.

For that I tried the command:

```
grep -o '2016[0-9]\{6\}' /var/named/test.com.db
```

But it outputs all those trash. I meant even digits with length more than 10

The result I am getting is:

```
> grep -o '2016[0-9]\{6\}' /var/named/test.com.db                     
2016071602
2016051010
2016051010
2016051010
2016051010
2016051010
2016051010
2016051010
2016051010
2016051010
```

Could you help me to filter this out properly?. Once I able to correct this one, I will be happy to proceed with mass zones update on the server.

Comment: @janos
I understand what you meant, which is:
grep -o '2016[0-9]\{6\}' /var/named/test.com.db | head -1
2016071602

But we can't always trust this will be the first match on the zone. Many zones are altered by cPanel migration script.

Comment: Usually "grep -o '2016[0-9]\{6\}'" should return only exactly 10 digit number right?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is not the best tool if you need a context, that is, some text around the pattern without including that text in the output.
`sed` with capture groups will work better, for example:

```
sed -ne 's/.*\(2016[0-9]\{6\}\).*Serial Number.*/\1/p' filename
```

This will print out the pattern captured within `\(...\)`,
when followed by "Serial Number" on the same line.
If this is not yet good enough, you can adjust the pattern accordingly,
making it more strict to eliminate further false positives.

Another useful trick is enclosing the interesting pattern within `\<...\>` to make it match word boundaries:

```
sed -ne 's/.*\<\(2016[0-9]\{6\}\)\>.*Serial Number.*/\1/p' filename
```

This way, cases like digits before 2016 or longer than 10 digits will not match.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `2016[0-9]\{6\}` matches any ten digits that begin with `2016`.  It places no limitations on what comes before or after those digits.

Try:

```
$ grep -Eo '2016[0-9]{6}[^0-9]' test.com.db 
2016071602
```

Or, better yet, if your grep supports `-P`, as it does on Linux systems:

```
$ grep -Po '2016[0-9]{6}(?=[^0-9])' test.com.db 
2016071602
```

Here, `(?=[^0-9])` is a look-ahead: it requires that a non-digit follow the number but it is not be included in the match.

Or, to get the number that is followed by "Serial Number":

```
$ grep -Po '2016[0-9]{6}(?=.*Serial Number)' test.com.db 
2016071602
```

This requires that the character after the ten digit number must be a non-digit.  (`[^0-9]` matches any non-digit because the `^` is the negation of what follows it.)

To make sure that this works with unicode fonts, you may want to replace `[0-9]` with its unicode-safe alternative: `[[:digit:]]`:

```
$ grep -Po '2016[[:digit:]]{6}(?=[^[:digit:]])' test.com.db 
2016071602
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly for me. Well explained too :)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep '^[^;].*Serial Number' file | grep -o '2016[0-9]\{6\}'
```

Output:

```
2016071602
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the output I wanted.